# If condition with multiple conditions and columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a list of stock column 27 is the bin and column 42 is the quantity. The argument is as follows If column 27 = SO000 and 42 = 0 then exclude them from the list this argument below works just fine for the 1 argument:

```
With WbCSV.Sheets(1)
    vDB = .UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        'AA column = 27, AP column = 42
        If vDB(i, 27) = "SO0000" And vDB(i, 42) = 0 Then
        Else
            'Get the contents corresponding to the dynamic array. Bring the matrix to the inverted state.
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
            vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(2, n) = vDB(i, 2)
            vR(3, n) = vDB(i, 3)
            vR(4, n) = vDB(i, 27)
            vR(5, n) = vDB(i, 42)
        End If
    Next i
End With
'Colse the text file
WbCSV.Close (0)
    
'The dynamic array is recorded in sheet2.Bring the row to the inverted state.
With Ws
    .UsedRange.Clear
    .Range("a1").Resize(n, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End With
Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:E").AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

But now I am stuck there is more arguments I need to add. If column 27 = WG0000 and col 42 = 0 then exlcude items. And SR0000 = 0 exclude from list.

Can someone please help me? Because I am not sure how to add more arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what argument you wish to add (`SR0000 = 0`?) but it sounds like you need an `elseif` statement.

```
With WbCSV.Sheets(1)
    vDB = .UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        'AA column = 27, AP column = 42
        If vDB(i, 27) = "SR0000" And vDB(i, 42) = 0 Then

        ElseIf vDB(i, 27) = "WG0000" And vDB(i, 42) = 0 Then
        'any further ElseIf statements can be added with a different set of conditions

        Else    'This gets triggered only if none of the If or ElseIf condition sets were met.
            'Get the contents corresponding to the dynamic array. Bring the matrix to the inverted state.
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
            vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 1)
            vR(2, n) = vDB(i, 2)
            vR(3, n) = vDB(i, 3)
            vR(4, n) = vDB(i, 27)
            vR(5, n) = vDB(i, 42)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, thanks for the reply. Basically yes there are 3 bins SO0000, SR0000 and WG0000, if their quantities are zero they should be excluded from the list that is pulled to sheet 2. I will test it and see if it works.